# Array of pointers to strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have the following;

```
const CHAR string_1[] PROGMEM = "String 1";
const CHAR string_2[] PROGMEM = "String 2";
const CHAR string_3[] PROGMEM = "String 3";
const CHAR string_4[] PROGMEM = "String 4";
const CHAR string_5[] PROGMEM = "String 5";

const CHAR *string_table[] PROGMEM  = 
{
    string_1,
    string_2,
    string_3,
    string_4,
    string_5
};
```

How would I save this address of string_table so I could call it in a function;

```
CHAR acBuffer[20];
UCHAR ucSelectedString = 2; // get string number 3
//
    pcStringTable = string_table ...?? What is the proper line here??
//
strcpy_P(acBuffer, (char*)pgm_read_byte(&(pcStringTable[ucSelectedString])))
```

Based on the comments below, I changed by structure too;

```
typedef struct
{
...
CHAR **pasOptions;
```

I then tried to assign `string_table` to it;

```
stMenuBar.pasOptions = string_table;
```

The compiler throws this warning;

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

Any more thoughts?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi I don't follow. Haven't I declared it in the struct?

Comment: I missed the fact that stmenubar is your unnamed struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string_table` is an array of pointers to strings. An array can decay to a (one-dimensional, because that's the only kind) pointer just fine.

So an array to arrays of strings can be represented as a pointer [think: array] to (pointers of chars [think: strings]).

```
const char **pcStringTable = string_table;
```

Which you can then access as any other one-dimensional array:

```
printf("%s", pcStringTable[2]);
```

Comment: The code in the OPs example is not a two-dimensional array, it is an array of pointers, which can decay into a pointer-to-pointer. When you downcast a pointer-to-pointer into a single pointer, you end up with a single pointer.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi I tried your suggestions, but to no avail. I have edited my original question.

Comment: That's just a const correctness warning. Since your strings are defined as `const char[]`, the string table variable must be `const char **` - I've fixed my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks - that did it. Is that even necessary when I declared them as PROGMEM?

Comment: That's an arduino-specific compiler command, it tells the compiler to store the variables in the flash instead of the main memory. It has nothing to do with the C code.